# Disable button if boolean variable is true

Tags: c#, asp.net, button

I've found topics covering disabling buttons to avoid submitting twice (assuming this could be done via javascript), but what i need is to disable button of submit if field "formSubmitted" in the database holds true value. otherwise this means the form has not been submitted and this submit is required. Any idea how to do this?

```
  <asp:TableCell>
        <asp:Button id="acceptButton" Text="Accept" runat="server" OnClick="Click"/> 
        <asp:Button id="declineButton" Text="Decline" runat="server" OnClick="DeclineRequest"/> 
    </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table></form></asp:Content>
```

so yeh the accept and decline buttons are what i want to disable if formsubmiited variable holds true.
Thanks again,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (formSubmitted)
{
    acceptButton.Enabled = false; 
    declineButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Enabled property.

```
if( WhateverYouAreTesting == true )
{
     declineButton.Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
declineButton.Enabled = booleanVariable == false;
```

Or

```
declineButton.Enabled = !booleanVariable;
```

Comment: Although the above answered what I wanted, but this is also a good manipulation that I may need later :)

Comment: The good thing about this approach is that you don't need another condition to enable the button. This is the only line of code you need to enabled and disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try

```
acceptButton.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(acceptButton.Enabled.Equals(true))
{
    acceptButton.Enabled = false;
}
```